# Why can't I have certain private member functions?

Tags: c++, class, private-members

Given a class, why can we implement certain private member functions, but not other private member functions? For instance, see below:

```
header file:
class A
{
    ....
    struct B
    {
    ....
    }
    int f(); 
    B* g();
}

cpp file:
int A::f(){...} // will compile
B*  A::g(){...} // will not compile!
```

The error is "Unknown type name 'B'", but my actual code has some more details.

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: "Unknown type name 'B'", my code has abit more details, but the function simply returns a nullptr

Answer (score 4):

```
B*  A::g(){...}
```

`B` is not visible outside `A`.

```
A::B*  A::g(){...}
```

This has nothing to do with private members. Since `B` is declared inside `A`, its not in global scope, hence you need to specify what `B` you are referring to.

Comment: Does this apply to all private member functions with privately defined type?

Comment: @LHC2012 Updated.

Comment: @LHC2012 -- the problem has nothing to do with marking things private. You'll have the same problem if everything is public. Try it: change `class A` to `struct A`.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively to the other answer you can use trailing return types

```
auto A::g() -> B* {...}
```

Before `A::g()` you have to use `A::B`. After `A::g()` you can simply use `B`.